# Can you vectorize a lookup loop in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm looking to set every element of an array based on looking up the value in a second array. Current doing it this way which works but is slow:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

colors = [
    [0, 255, 0],    # GREEN
    [255, 0, 0],    # BLUE
    [0, 0, 255],    # RED
]

WIDTH = 400
HEIGHT = 400
target = np.zeros((HEIGHT, WIDTH, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
color_lookup = np.random.randint(0, len(colors), (HEIGHT, WIDTH))

for i in range(target.shape[0]):
    for j in range(target.shape[1]):
        target[i, j] = colors[color_lookup[i, j]]

cv2.imshow("target", target)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

What is the correct way to vectorize that loop instead?

Comment: As a side note, you can also write `target[color_lookup == 0] = colors[0]`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `colors` *isn't* an array. It's a list of lists. NumPy can't vectorize a lookup that's handled by list code instead of NumPy code.

Use an array instead:

```
colors = np.array([
    [0, 255, 0],    # GREEN
    [255, 0, 0],    # BLUE
    [0, 0, 255],    # RED
], dtype='uint8')
```

and then it'll support vectorized lookups:

```
target = colors[color_lookup]
```

as well as more complex indexing operations, which you can read about in the [NumPy indexing docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html).